# Do you have to close the thread once it has ended when using pthreads in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, winapi, pthreads

In WinAPI, if you create a thread and this thread is then ended, you still have to call [CloseHandle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx) on the thread handle.

When using pthreads in Linux, do you also have to close the thread after it has ended?

Comment: That happens when you *join* the (non-detached) thread. If you don't join the (non-detached) thread, you have a resource leak until the process ends.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in pthreads is to call `pthread_join()` on the thread (this will block until the thread exits, if it hasn't already).

You also have the option to detach the thread with `pthread_detach()` (or create it detached using the `attr` argument to `pthread_create()` with `pthread_attr_setdetachstate()`), which means the thread no longer needs to be joined.

Comment: 2 notes. 1. Good to know, there is no builtin way of joining any thread. 2. Zombies, see manpage quote: 'Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is not detached), produces a "zombie thread".  Avoid doing this, since each zombie thread consumes some system resources, and when enough zombie threads have accumulated, it will no longer be possible to create new threads (or processes).'